# How use a config.json in root directory with React?

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch

I want to use a **config.json** file located in root directory in React. The reason of this is because i will need update this file json whitout rebuild project.

**Project estructure:**

```
> /build
> /node_modules
> /public
> /src
> config.json
> package.json
...ect.
```

What i try?

**[Try 1] Import from root directory..**

```
import { configUrl } from "./../../config.json";
```

**[Try 2] Add into dependencies**

```
"@project-name": "file:./config.json"
```

And import into react component

```
import { configUrl } from "@project-name";
```

To finally use fetch:

```
return fetch(configUrl, requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

But noone work, what more can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to put your `config.json` file in public folder in the root dir of your React app and then fetch it in the top most component of your app.

```js
async function getConfig {

const res = await fetch('/config.json');
const config = res.json();

}
```

`'/config.json'` This url will work because all unidentified endpoints are redirected to public folder.

**CAUTION: If your react app is hosted it will let anyone access your config file with above url.**

Comment: But if i put in public, i will need rebuild project if i need change something, true? i dont want rebuild.

Comment: No you can just replace or edit config.json file and restart your app

Comment: @AntonioRuiz There should be public folder in build output of react app change your config.json there.